# Parsing Json response with google json

Tags: java, json, wordpress, gson

I am using wordpress [json-api](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/json-api/other_notes/) plugin and want to call get_date_index. The json response of the function is in below format.

```
{
"status": "ok",
"permalinks": [
 "...",
"...",
"..."
],
"tree": {
"2009": {
  "09": 17,
  "10": 20,
  "11": 7
},
"2010":{
 }
}
```

Note: the tree is arranged by response.tree.[year].[month].[number of posts].

How do i parse this response with java Parcelable object? I am using google json to parse the response. I am not able to understand how to write the java object for tree response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF you mean [google-gson](http://google-gson.googlecode.com) the docs say something to this effect:

```
 Gson gson = new Gson(); // Or use new GsonBuilder().create();
 MyType target = new MyType();
 MyType target2 = gson.fromJson(json, MyType.class); // deserializes json into target2
```

`json` would be the string responseText.

Comment: Is the line `MyType target = new MyType();` necessary?

Comment: @prodigitalson thanks for your reply... 
`public String status;

    public String [] permalinks;

    public Map<String, Map<Integer,Integer>> tree = new HashMap<String, Map<Integer,Integer>>();`

I was able to parse the response using the above map.